# What are the valid image formats for Solana NFTs?

Tags: solana, nft, erc721

Every tutorial I've seen and every single example in the doc shows PNG files. But I can't find any documentation that explicitly states that this is the only supported format. Is it possible to mint an NFT with a JPG file or something else?

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** All image formats with the `image/*` mime type.

---

Reasoning behind the statement:

1. Solana is a platform allowing for smart contracts (called Programs) written in Rust, C, and C++ ([source](https://solana.com/news/getting-started-with-solana-development)). There are also some unofficial tools that allow you to compile contracts written in other languages, such [Solang](https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/solang) for Solidity.
2. There are smart contract standards, usually defined as an interface and a set of rules (such as when to emit specific events), originated in the Ethereum ecosystem as EIPs (Ethereum Improvement Protocol). One of them is [EIP-721](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md) which is the first approved, and widely used, NFT standard.

   You as a developer, are able to create an NFT smart contract that doesn't follow any of the EIP standards. But, a common practice is to follow the original standards even though you're developing on another network (such as Solana), respecting network-specific differences.
3. The EIP-721 standard explicitly describes the `image` field of the metadata JSON:

   > *A URI pointing to a resource with mime type `image/*` representing the asset to which this NFT represents.*

*Note: The standard is also referred to as ERC-721. ERC is a subset type of EIP, and both names are correct.*

Comment: Thanks, Peter. Is it just coincidence that every doc or tutorial example I've ever seen shows a PNG? Is there a reason why that seems most common?

Comment: For a bit more context, I was recently experimenting with Metaplex's candy-machine library and it did not seem to support any formats besides PNG. That might be a temporary bug... I guess I'm wondering if in your experience other formats are _theoretically_ valid (according to the spec), or if they're actually used in practice.

Comment: @emersonthis I'm not familiar with the Metaplex libraries, but from what I [found](https://docs.metaplex.com/nft-standard): "PNG, GIF and JPG file formats are supported" (quote from the linked docs page). I understand that some 3rd party libraries can have limitations on their app level, disallowing some of the less used image formats... I personally haven't seen any other format apart from PNG to be used as an underlying resource for an NFT, but in my understanding of the standard - any other image format (assuming it's `image/*` mimetype) is theoretically valid.